# Putting sess.run output into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

So my code has the line in it and it works:

```
    _, loss_value0, loss_value1, loss_value2, loss_value3 = sess.run([train_op, loss0, loss1, loss2, loss3])
```

I wanted to make this a list of losses so I ran:

```
    loss_value_list = []
    _, loss_value_list = sess.run([train_op] + loss_list)
```

But that doesn't work. Probably I can't assign a list like that? Is there someway to do that?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to pre define the `loss_value_list`; Use `*` operator to unpack the result into a list variable instead:

```
lst = ['a', 1, 2, 3, 4]
_, *loss_value_list = lst

loss_value_list
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Ok thanks! Gonna try it out tommorow and come back :)